# Multilevel model with interaction effect in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I'm fairly new to statistical analysis, but was told to use a multilevel model for my research purpose. I am interested in investigating whether attitudes on the EU integration are different for left and right wing individuals in countries with stronger and weaker welfare state. For this I would like to use an interaction term.

```
model04 <- lmer(eu_idt_std ~ 1 + leftright_std*redistribution_std 
                + (1 + leftright_std | cntry), 
                data = analysis,
                REML=F,
                na.action=na.exclude)
```

I was also wondering whether it might be smarter to specify the model like this:

```
model04 <- lmer(eu_idt_std ~ 1 + leftright_std*redistribution_std 
                + (1 | cntry) + (0 + leftright_std | cntry), 
                data = analysis,
                REML=F,
                na.action=na.exclude)
```

The actual model includes more control variables and here is some of my data.

```
structure(list(cntry = c("BG", "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG"), 
    regunit = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), label = "Regional unit", format.stata = "%3.0g", labels = c(`NUTS level 1` = 1, 
    `NUTS level 2` = 2, `NUTS level 3` = 3, `Regional unit not part of the NUTS nomenclature` = 4
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    region = c("BG422", "BG411", "BG411", "BG342", "BG422", "BG314"
    ), lrscale = structure(c(8, 4, 8, 7, 5, NA), label = "Placement on left right scale", format.stata = "%4.0g", labels = c(Left = 0, 
    `1` = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7` = 7, 
    `8` = 8, `9` = 9, Right = 10, Refusal = NA, `Don't know` = NA, 
    `No answer` = NA), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), gincdif = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4), euftf = structure(c(10, 
    8, 10, 9, 4, 5), label = "European Union: European unification go further or gone too far", format.stata = "%4.0g", labels = c(`Unification already gone too far` = 0, 
    `1` = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7` = 7, 
    `8` = 8, `9` = 9, `Unification go further` = 10, Refusal = NA, 
    `Don't know` = NA, `No answer` = NA), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), atchctr = structure(c(10, 8, 8, 
    10, 10, 5), label = "How emotionally attached to [country]", format.stata = "%4.0g", labels = c(`Not at all emotionally attached` = 0, 
    `1` = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7` = 7, 
    `8` = 8, `9` = 9, `Very emotionally attached` = 10, Refusal = NA, 
    `Don't know` = NA, `No answer` = NA), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), atcherp = structure(c(10, 8, 7, 
    3, 10, 3), label = "How emotionally attached to Europe", format.stata = "%4.0g", labels = c(`Not at all emotionally attached` = 0, 
    `1` = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7` = 7, 
    `8` = 8, `9` = 9, `Very emotionally attached` = 10, Refusal = NA, 
    `Don't know` = NA, `No answer` = NA), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), gndr = structure(c(2, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1), label = "Gender", format.stata = "%3.0g", labels = c(Male = 1, 
    Female = 2, `No answer` = NA), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), agea = structure(c(56, 55, 25, 
    58, 67, 77), label = "Age of respondent, calculated", format.stata = "%5.0g", labels = c(`Not available` = NA_real_), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), eduyrs = structure(c(18, 16, 17, 
    12, 12, 11), label = "Years of full-time education completed", format.stata = "%4.0g", labels = c(Refusal = NA_real_, 
    `Don't know` = NA_real_, `No answer` = NA_real_), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), female = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), leftright = c(8, 
    4, 8, 7, 5, NA), euint_opn = c(10, 8, 10, 9, 4, 5), cntry_idt = c(10, 
    8, 8, 10, 10, 5), eu_idt = c(10, 8, 7, 3, 10, 3), yrs_edu = c(18, 
    16, 17, 12, 12, 11), age = c(56, 55, 25, 58, 67, 77), gdp_pc = c(25169.908002, 
    25169.908002, 25169.908002, 25169.908002, 25169.908002, 25169.908002
    ), Country = c("Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
    "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria"), year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2019), market_gini = c(0.523, 0.523, 0.523, 0.523, 
    0.523, 0.523), post_gini = c(0.402, 0.402, 0.402, 0.402, 
    0.402, 0.402), redistribution = c(0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 
    0.121, 0.121), gincdif_cen = c(0.0382937934339802, -0.96170620656602, 
    0.0382937934339802, -0.96170620656602, 1.03829379343398, 
    1.03829379343398), leftright_cen = c(2.6442974848222, -1.3557025151778, 
    2.6442974848222, 1.6442974848222, -0.355702515177797, NA), 
    euint_opn_cen = c(4.46396603754284, 2.46396603754284, 4.46396603754284, 
    3.46396603754284, -1.53603396245716, -0.536033962457164), 
    cntry_idt_cen = c(1.76904445288754, -0.230955547112462, -0.230955547112462, 
    1.76904445288754, 1.76904445288754, -3.23095554711246), eu_idt_cen = c(3.93090891667864, 
    1.93090891667864, 0.930908916678645, -3.06909108332136, 3.93090891667864, 
    -3.06909108332136), yrs_edu_cen = c(5.02001824204311, 3.02001824204311, 
    4.02001824204311, -0.979981757956891, -0.979981757956891, 
    -1.97998175795689), age_cen = c(5.15717539863326, 4.15717539863326, 
    -25.8428246013667, 7.15717539863326, 16.1571753986333, 26.1571753986333
    ), gdp_pc_cen = c(-14836.5688141943, -14836.5688141943, -14836.5688141943, 
    -14836.5688141943, -14836.5688141943, -14836.5688141943), 
    market_gini_cen = c(0.0335484709552394, 0.0335484709552394, 
    0.0335484709552394, 0.0335484709552394, 0.0335484709552394, 
    0.0335484709552394), post_gini_cen = c(0.0945660537883443, 
    0.0945660537883443, 0.0945660537883443, 0.0945660537883443, 
    0.0945660537883443, 0.0945660537883443), redistribution_cen = c(-0.0610175828331049, 
    -0.0610175828331049, -0.0610175828331049, -0.0610175828331049, 
    -0.0610175828331049, -0.0610175828331049), excl_natidt = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), gincdif_std = structure(c(0.0381855950433824, 
    -0.958988923830432, 0.0381855950433824, -0.958988923830432, 
    1.0353601139172, 1.0353601139172), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), leftright_std = structure(c(1.16632317376368, 
    -0.597961186007741, 1.16632317376368, 0.725252083820824, 
    -0.156890096064886, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), euint_opn_std = structure(c(1.71185048703875, 
    0.944886548405815, 1.71185048703875, 1.32836851772228, -0.589041328860047, 
    -0.205559359543581), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), cntry_idt_std = structure(c(0.895957635755242, 
    -0.116970710158064, -0.116970710158064, 0.895957635755242, 
    0.895957635755242, -1.63636322902802), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), 
    eu_idt_std = structure(c(1.52801804197905, 0.750580520852194, 
    0.361861760288766, -1.19301328196495, 1.52801804197905, -1.19301328196495
    ), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), yrs_edu_std = structure(c(1.24083228276956, 
    0.746478588044916, 0.993655435407238, -0.24222880140437, 
    -0.24222880140437, -0.489405648766692), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), 
    age_std = structure(c(0.28064162523024, 0.22622392493162, 
    -1.40630708402697, 0.389477025827479, 0.879236328515057, 
    1.42341333150125), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), gdp_pc_std = structure(c(-1.54102451499488, 
    -1.54102451499488, -1.54102451499488, -1.54102451499488, 
    -1.54102451499488, -1.54102451499488), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), 
    market_gini_std = structure(c(0.984810228681162, 0.984810228681162, 
    0.984810228681162, 0.984810228681162, 0.984810228681162, 
    0.984810228681162), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), post_gini_std = structure(c(2.04823627978607, 
    2.04823627978607, 2.04823627978607, 2.04823627978607, 2.04823627978607, 
    2.04823627978607), .Dim = c(6L, 1L)), redistribution_std = structure(c(-1.62906248185286, 
    -1.62906248185286, -1.62906248185286, -1.62906248185286, 
    -1.62906248185286, -1.62906248185286), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then plotted the residuals and assume that this pattern is somewhat problematic.

```
res <- resid(model04)
plot(fitted(model04), res)
```

I can however not fully make sense of this pattern and would very much appreciate if someone with more experience in handling this type of model/data could maybe give me some hints?

Comment: If your first model runs then I definitely don't recommend the second one you suggest (random intercept + random slope without the correlation), because you're forcing the correlation between intercepts and slopes to be 0 (rather than estimating it freely), which will almost certainly decrease fit and doesn't seem otherwise useful unless you explicitly think that the correlation should be 0 for some reason

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe thanks, that makes sense! Do you have any advice about the distribution of the residuals?

Comment: when I have a numeric dependent variable and nesting/random effects, I model it with a multilevel model almost without exception without paying much attention to the assumptions (rightfully or not). Also if it's anything like regression (which I assume it is) the model should be relatively robust to violation of the specific assumption of normally-distributed residuals.